# CSOM Error 409 because Slide is opend by another user

Tags: development, client-object-model, csom

I am getting an error 409 while trying to write a file in a slide library. All I found on google until now is about wrong paths. But I already wrote about 90 other files in the exact same library until I get to the slide on which the exception is trhown. My guess is that I cannot write the file because another user has opened it, since I get the message that the file is currently in use when I try to open it manually. How can I check that and skip the corresponding file?

```
try
{
    // Creating the Clientcontext
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sharePointAdress);
    SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "pwd".ToCharArray()) pwd.AppendChar(c);

    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("login", pwd);
    Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;

    // Collect all lists from Sharepoint.
    ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;
    clientContext.Load(collList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Sharepoint.");

    // Getting the Presentation.
    List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(id);
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    String queryString = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileExtension'><Value Type='text'>pptx</Value></FieldRef></Eq></Where>";    // FileLeafRef is the column "name" on the Sharepoint.
    camlQuery.ViewXml = @queryString;
    ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    clientContext.Load(listItems, item => item.Include(f => f.File));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    Console.WriteLine("Opened Document.");

    foreach (var file in listItems)
    {
        clientContext.Load(file);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        filename = file["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Working on " + filename + "..");
        currentID = file["ID"].ToString();
        FileInformation fileInformation = ClientOM.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)file["FileRef"]);

        if(file.File.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                fileInformation.Stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(memoryStream, true);

                // Working on the files..

                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                ClientOM.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)item["FileRef"], memoryStream, true);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to do something similar to where I am checking if the file is checked out.

Comment: Can you share your essential part of code? I need to know how you got **file** object.

Comment: Added the Information to the OP

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to explicitly load the `CheckOutType` before using it.

Your code to load the list item should look similar to

```
clientContext.Load(listItem, item => item.File.CheckOutType, item => item.File.CheckedOutByUser, item => item.File.LockedByUser);
```

in place of

```
clientContext.Load(listItems, item => item.Include(f => f.File));
```

Adjust the variable as per requirement.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29929712) for original post

Comment: I had to adjust your solution slightly: `clientContext.Load(listItems, item => item.Include(i => i.File.CheckOutType, i => i.File.CheckedOutByUser, i => i.File.LockedByUser));` But it does seem to work for now. Could you elaborate why? I'd like to understand my error.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as below

```
foreach (var file in listItems)
{
    if(file.File.CheckOutType == CheckOutType.None)
    {
        // Do things
        clientContext.Load(file);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        filename = file["FileLeafRef"].ToString();
        Console.WriteLine("Working on " + filename + "..");
        currentID = file["ID"].ToString();
        FileInformation fileInformation = ClientOM.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, (string)file["FileRef"]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Also I don't think you need to Load File again because you have explicitly requested for that as part of your initial listitems query

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work, since the file is not checked out. It is just locked.

Comment: Update - Check file.LockId and if it is not empty then it means it is locked